# After Registration Page Gets Blank Opencart 1.5

Tags: opencart, registration, opencart2.x

I'm having a online shop where at registration page after filling up details user is registered but page gets blank , any Idea whats happening .After checking Error logs i find out error like this

```
PHP Notice:  Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This question is very broad.  Consider editing it to include the code for the registration page and a detailed description of what the user enters, what they click and what you see along with the final error message.

Comment: @J Richard Snape , When user enters all mandatory details it registers user but unable continues with blank page

Comment: OK - I'm not an opencart expert who can help with your issue. But I think anyone who can will need to know what you expect to see - i.e. what page you expect to see after registration.

Comment: Success Page i.e success.php

Answer (score 0):

Go into Admin > System > Settings > Mail

If you have SMTP set change it to PHP Mailer that should resolve your issue